# React useState entering infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am using setInterval to increment the count and show it on a div like below. I am sure that the incrementcount is working nice. Dont know what mistake I am doing.

```
function DivClicker() {
 const [count, setCount] = React.useState<number>(0);

 function incrementCount():void{
    setCount((prev)=>prev+1);
 }
 setInterval(incrementCount,1000);

  return (
    <div>
        <div className='middle-div'>
            <div>{count}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DivClicker;
```

It is going crazy and incrementing hugely in matter of seconds.. Kindly guide. Mostly it is going in an infinite loop. I dont know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not only setting state each render - causing an infinite loop, but you're adding a **new** interval that sets state each render. So each time you're adding more and more infinite setStates.

Fix this by setting your interval only once in a `useEffect`:

```
function DivClicker() {
 const [count, setCount] = React.useState<number>(0);

 function incrementCount():void{
    setCount((prev)=>prev+1);
 }
 
 useEffect(() => {
   const interval = setInterval(incrementCount,1000);

   return () => clearInterval(interval);
 }, []);

  return (
    <div>
        <div className='middle-div'>
            <div>{count}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DivClicker;
```

If you get an es-lint warning about a missing dependency, you can move `incrementCount` into the `useEffect`.

Comment: Aha, so once setInterval calls setState, component is rerenderred and again setInterval is called.. and again setState, for each render... Yes I get it... thanks

Comment: @Abhijeet Yes, but actually a little worse. Each render it creates a *new* interval. So after two renders you're calling setState twice each time, and after three it sets state 3 times, etc.. So you have an infinite loop that's speeding up exponentially.

Comment: I think it would be better to assign interval to a variable, and return clearInteval from useEffect to avoid memory leaks. ```return () => clearInteval(myInterval)```

Comment: @VladimirTrotsenko You're right

Comment: Yes I get all of this.. Thanks..You guys are great!